# Nest Scheduler - Cron decorator is missing dependencies when combined with other decorator via applyDecorators

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, cron, nestjs, scheduling

I am trying to build a cron decorator which also logs the name of the task when it is executed.
To do this, I am combining the default nestjs scheduling Cron decorator with a custom LogTask decorator in the following file:

```js
//cron-with-log.decorator.ts

const CronWithLog = (
  taskName: string,
  cronTime: string | Date,
  options?: CronOptions,
) => {
  return applyDecorators(LogTask(taskName), Cron(cronTime, options));
};

export default CronWithLog;
```

```js
//log-task.decorator.ts

const LogTask = (taskName) => {
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const targetFunc = descriptor.value;
    const logger = new Logger('Scheduler');
    descriptor.value = (...args: any[]) => {
      logger.log(`Executing Task: ${taskName}`);
      targetFunc.apply(this, args);
    };
    return descriptor;
  };
};

export default LogTask;
```

Here is how I use it:

```
@Injectable()
export class Task {
  constructor(
    private readonly taskService: TaskService,
  ) {}

  @CronWithLog('Example Task', '* * * * * *')
  async run() {
    console.log(taskService.get(1))
  }
}
```

The logging works:

`[Nest] 98   - 02/12/2021, 7:36:07 AM   [Scheduler] Executing Task: Example Task`

but the dependency `TaskService` is not getting initialized, and the task itself fails. If I switch the order of the decorators in `applyDecorators` of my `cron-with-log.ts` to `applyDecorators(Cron(cronTime, options), LogTask(taskName))`, neither the logging nor the task is executed. Running the job with the default Cron decorator works also fine.

Am I missing something to get the dependencies initialized in my LogTask function?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the arrow function used here:

```
descriptor.value = (...args: any[]) => {
      logger.log(`Executing Task: ${taskName}`);
      targetFunc.apply(this, args);
    };
```

by using it, `this` was only holding the reference to the decorator itself. Replacing it with `function (...args: any[]) {...}` gives you the instance of the  class in which the decorator is used in `this` and with it, all the initialized dependencies.